# Who can get access to Visual Studio Team Services Package Management feeds?

Tags: visual-studio, package-management, team-foundation-server

I'm considering using the Package Management extension for my team, but I've found the documentation to be unclear on how access to feeds is allotted.  Is it possible to have "collaborators" (who don't count as "users" in VSTS) get access, or do only full VSTS users have the ability to authenticate to the feeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only **users with VS Enterprise access** to TFS are able to get to the Package Management "feeds.

Tip: For onprem TFS you can review who has that access level (or set it as Default access for all) here -- http://{TFS}:8080/tfs/_admin/_licenses

For Team Services, here's how to manage access for users -- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/add-account-users-assign-access-levels-team-services